# Cannot download web page html, times out

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webclient, downloadstring

I've tried everything I could find on these pages, `Webclient`, `HttpClient`, `HttpWebRequest` etc. I've looked at fiddler and copied all the cookies, added all the same headers and user agents etc. These all work for almost every other page I try, but for some reason Toys'R'Us just times out. Everything was working fine yesterday, it just seems to have stopped working today.

First time I've posted here but could somebody just try any method for downloading the html for a random example of:

http://www.toysrus.co.uk/toys/transformers-robots-in-disguise-strongarm-one-step-changers/0148891

No matter what I've tried it just seems to hang and timeout. The really annoying thing is that it loads fine in chrome, internet explorer, fiddler... I just can't seem to get it to download in c# regardless of downloadstring, `HttpWebRequest` etc, it just seems to hang and timeout.

To be clear, I had this working yesterday and has been for months, something must have changed on their servers but I can't figure out what.

If somebody could try it and test if it's just my setup that's failing I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Just tested it. Same result as you.

Comment: Thanks Gianlucca, not just me being stupid then... anybody any idea what's going on here then?

Answer (score 1):

very odd this, finally got it working by adding these specific headers:

Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*

Accept-Language: en-GB

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

on a webclient downloadstring. I'm sure I tried this yesterday... but it's now working today. They must have changed something back their end I guess. Anyway... can carry on now. Thanks again Gianlucca.